# change title separator

Tags: title, get-the-title, wp-title

tell me how permanent the links to change the splitter from vertical to horizontal of the main page write website. | — 
http://joxi.ru/a2XlxQXcyeKPj2

The name of the site | short name
The name of the site — short name

Comment: So you want to change the `|` to a `-` in the google search results? I don't think there's enough info to determine that in your question at the moment, we'd need to know how the `|` got there and how it's displayed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything is simple, there is a standard wordpress options and settings of the SEO plugin, I'm involved in the standard settings, a vertical divider as to remove it entirely from the functions of the theme?